# Passing non-datatable parameter in the table with Datatable parameters using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have only 2 columns/parameters in the Datatable which I am trying to insert in the table through stored procedure.

But I also want to add another parameter which is not in the DataTable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Job].[prc_A]
@JobId int = 0,
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@JobPropertyValue as JobPropertyValuesType READONLY
```

Here is the query:

```
if(@JobId = 0)
    BEGIN
INSERT INTO TableA (StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES(@StartDate, @EndDate)
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)

---A New JobId gets created after first insert query. I want to add that JobId in Table B now with DataTable Parameters---
INSERT INTO TableB (JobId, JobPropertyType, JobValue)
    SELECT  __________________, JobPropertyType, JobPropertyTypeName  
    FROM @JobPropertyValue
```

(using stored procedure)

What's the right way to insert JobId which is present in a different table and other two parameters from DataTable?
(I don't want to make any changes to the Code part or Adding the JobId(Fetching it from the Table) in the DataTable directly)
I am using Asp.Net Core in to send request.

Comment: I've removed almost all the tags here. I don't see, in the above, what this has to do with C# (other than your application is using it, which doesn't seem related to the question) and you've tagged SQL Server and MySQL here. [Edit] your question and tag correctly please.

Comment: You **must NOT** use any parenthesis in your `SELECT` statement - just drop the `(` and `)`

Comment: I added beck the SqlServer and T-Sql tags, the `@` makes it clear they must have meant that.  (i.e., the "MSSQL" misnomer confuses yet another asker).

Comment: `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)` Why? Why do you need to cast? You pass Job ID as an int parameter - so casting does not appear to be needed. And this entire approach seems to be over-complicated. How does inserting a row into TableA cause a new Job ID to be created in "Table B" (as noted in the comment) while you seem to ignore the identity value that your procedure returns as a resultset with `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)`?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Job Id is created in one table. I just want to add some data in a different table (using datatable) and want to take JobId from that table and add data corresponding to it.  @SMor

Comment: @SMor `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `decimal(38,0)` so it does make sense to cast. Yes, the cast will happen implicitly anyway, but some prefer to be explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming TABLEA's IDENTITY column is the JobId, then just

```
if(@JobId = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA (StartDate, EndDate)
    VALUES(@StartDate, @EndDate)
    set @jobid  = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

    ---A New JobId gets created after first insert query. I want to add that JobId in Table B now with DataTable Parameters---
    INSERT INTO TableB (JobId, JobPropertyType, JobValue)
        SELECT  @jobid, JobPropertyType, JobPropertyTypeName  
        FROM @JobPropertyValue
```